# indent cl-loop to respect `if else` statements

Tags: indentation, cl-lib

I have a hard time writing and reading cl-loops with they way they're indented by default as I can't easily tell what the control flow is:

```
(cl-loop for x below 10
         if (cl-oddp x)
         collect x into odds
         and if (memq x funny-numbers) return (cdr it) end
         else
         collect x into evens
         finally return (vector odds evens))
```

I'd like it to be indented like how it's shown in its documentation:

```
(cl-loop for x below 10
         if (cl-oddp x)
           collect x into odds
           and if (memq x funny-numbers) return (cdr it) end
         else
           collect x into evens
         finally return (vector odds evens))
```

I know this has to do with `Indenting Macros` manual page. And possibly [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/why-does-emacs-indent-my-lisp-loop-construct-weirdly) on indenting a common lisp loop in emacs. Additionally, I've looked at [a post](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=2226) on irreal and [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/modifying-the-indentation-of-some-emacs-lisp-forms) on the indentation of lisp forms.

The general idea I got from reading is to use `(declare (indent n))` where n is an integer. I see this works for simple examples. However, how I want the `cl-loop` to be indented seems too complex for this. I need to tell emacs to recognize the specific `if` `else` keywords in the cl-loop.

I am confused as I don't see a clear way to properly indent `cl-loop`. Any ideas?

Comment: The declaration `(debug ...)` is for Edebug.

Comment: Oh, ok. It doesn't have to do with indentation. I'll remove it from my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can achieve your desired indentation style by doing

```
(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result in either 27.2 or 28.  Does this also work for you in `emacs -Q -l cl-lib` ?  If so, which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: I am using emacs 27.2 on Windows 10. This works for me when I invoke Emacs using `emacs -Q -l cl-lib`

Comment: Okay I tried the example above and it didn't work. But when I use this setting on my own code example it has better indentation than the default for elisp:

`(cl-loop
     for n below arg
     do
       (setq pt (point))
       (when (org-at-table-p)
         (goto-char (org-table-end))
     if (re-search-forward org-table-line-regexp nil t) do
       (when (org-invisible-p)
         (org-reveal t)
         (org-show-entry)
         (unless (org-at-table-p)
           (cl-decf n)))
     else return (goto-char pt))`

Comment: There are some differences, but it doesn't look like your example behaves any differently WRT the if/then/else indentation (which was what the question was specifically about).